# How can I have an (InDesign) paragraph style without a paragraph break (running paragraphs)?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I'm creating a small brochure using a design based on Eric Gill's "An Essay on Typography." Specifically, I have (A) paragraphs for each main idea that are new paragraphs (aligned left) starting with a pilcrow with (B) "sub-paragraphs" that elaborate on that main idea start with a pilcrow, but with no paragraph break (see image). I do want the pilcrows visible as in the example.

[image: Sample page from Gill's essay]

I'm using paragraph numbering with the pilcrow character as the "number" to achieve the first level. What I can't figure out is how to achieve the second level using paragraph styles. I can simply insert the pilcrow manually and keep going, all in the main paragraph style, but I am now curious if there is a way to achieve this with a second paragraph style for the subparagraphs?

Comment: I don't think its possible. What about using character styles and grep?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to actually insert the character as a visible mark in the output, then the easiest thing in my mind is to place particular character (or a double-space) in your imported copy and do a find-and-change after the fact

Comment: Thanks. I do want the pilcrows visible, as in the example. Inserting it on the fly is fine too, but I was hoping to be able to adjust formatting of subparagraphs using styles just as I can the main paragraphs (particularly if I change my mind about having the subparagraphs be identical in formatting). It's a bit of a mind-exercise at this point since for something this short, manually fiddling is fine!